# Parent property in css file at angular

Tags: css

I have css file which has style for a lot of color (I show only two at below). And all properties are the same except background color. So I want parent style like `bgGrid` and only define in other like my example. How can I do this? **I know, I can write two class to my HTML but I have no chance to change html**. So, I'm looking for like below. How can I do this?

```
bgGridBlue {
  width: 102%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: -1%;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bgGridRed {
  width: 102%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: -1%;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

What I was looking for:

```
bgGrid {
  width: 102%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: -1%;
  color: white;
}

bgGridBlue {
  include bgGrid ????
  background-color: blue;
}

.bgGridRed {
  include bgGrid ????
  background-color: red;
}
```

my HTML

```
<div class="bgGridRed"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best place to start is @[SASS_LANG](https://sass-lang.com/guide) for scss/sass basics:

To your specific case:

```
%grid { // extend option
  width: 102%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: -1%;
  color: white;
}

.bgGridRed { // repeat for each colour
  @extend %grid;
  background-color: red;
}
```

You could also do use of mixins like:

```
@mixin coloredGrid($color) { //mixin option
  width: 102%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-left: -1%;
  color: white;
  background-color: $color;
}

.bgGridRed { // repeat for each colour
  @include coloredGrid(red);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It will solve my problem.Thanks @T04435

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `<div class="bgGrid red"></div>` and/or `<div class="bgGrid blue"></div>`. Use main bgGrid class and depend on your need change the second class dynamically from the component or ....

You can look at this [tutorial](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-ngclass).

Comment: Because, that part is very complex and dynamic. So, I want achieve without touching dynamic part. @vancho

Comment: You can use one function like a class in html <div [ngClass]="setMyClasses()"></div> and in component change it setMyClasses() {
  let classes = {
    "width": "102%",
    "font-weight": "bold",
    "display": "inline-block",
    "padding": "4px",
    "margin-left": "-1%",
    "color": "white",
    "background-color": this.color
  };
  return classes;
} And depend on background change this property from component

Answer (score 0):

Class bindings do not work? Since you still have to decide on the setting of bgGridBlue or bgGridRed somewhere, on that place do this instead:

```
<div class="bgGrid" [ngClass]="{ blue: item.fromBlueCategory, red: item.fromRedCategory }"></div>
```

Or if it's more complex, get that decided in the component:

```
<div class="bgGrid"
  [class.blue]="isColor('blue', item)"
  [class.red]="isColor('red', item)"
  ..
></div>

// then in component:
isColor(colorName: string, item: any) {
  if (item.something.blah && this.service.whatever) {
    return true;
  } else if (anotherReason) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Then you simply define CSS classes for background as the other answers suggest.